# Zoom Control in Camera is not working in Android

Tags: android, camera, zooming

I am working on Custom Camera using Surface view in my application, also recording Video with screen Capture.

I am looking to implement Zoom Control in my Camera Code but not getting success.

Getting this log while Zooming:

```
E/Adreno200-ES20(12756): <qgl2DrvAPI_glBufferSubData:709>: GL_INVALID_OPERATION
```

I am using below code:

/**
 * setZoomControl
 * @param params
 */

```
public void setZoomControl(Camera.Parameters params) {
    paramtrs = params;
    ZoomControls zoomControls = (ZoomControls) findViewById(R.id.zoomcontrols);

    if (params.isZoomSupported()) {
        final int maxZoomLevel = paramtrs.getMaxZoom();
        Log.i("max ZOOM ", "is " + maxZoomLevel);

        zoomControls.setIsZoomInEnabled(true);
        zoomControls.setIsZoomOutEnabled(true);

        zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int currentZoomLevel = 0;
                if (currentZoomLevel < maxZoomLevel) {
                    currentZoomLevel++;
                    camera.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                }
            }
        });

        zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                int currentZoomLevel = 0;
                if (currentZoomLevel > 0) {
                    currentZoomLevel--;
                    camera.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                }
            }
        });
    } else
        zoomControls.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

Please suggest me whats happening in my code.

Answer (score 4):

> You can use this code

```
if (params.isZoomSupported()) {
        final int maxZoomLevel = params.getMaxZoom();
        Log.i("max ZOOM ", "is " + maxZoomLevel);
        zoomControls.setIsZoomInEnabled(true);
        zoomControls.setIsZoomOutEnabled(true);

        zoomControls.setOnZoomInClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(currentZoomLevel < maxZoomLevel){
                    currentZoomLevel++;
                    //mCamera.startSmoothZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                    params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                    mCamera.setParameters(params);
                }
            }
        });

        zoomControls.setOnZoomOutClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                if(currentZoomLevel > 0){
                    currentZoomLevel--;
                    params.setZoom(currentZoomLevel);
                    mCamera.setParameters(params);
                }
            }
        });    
    }
    else
        zoomControls.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```